# Prime Numbers python

Tags: python

I'm a beginning programmer in python and have a question about my code I'm writing:

```
number = int(input("Enter a random number: "))

for num in range(1, number + 1) :
    for i in range(2, num) :
         if (num % i) == 0 :
            break
         else :
             print(num)
             break
```

When I run this program I also get 9, 15 21 as output. But these are not prime numbers. 
What is wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check that your indentation is correct. The 2nd for loop should be indented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `if (num % i) == 0:` you go to the `else` block for every `num`, which is not a multiply of 2, as you start `i` with 2, thus printing `num`. I got all odd numbers printed with your code.

You can use something like this:

```
number = int(input("Enter a random number: "))

for num in range(1, number + 1):
    prime = True
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            prime = False
            break
    if prime:
        print(num)
```

It sets `prime` to `False` when it encounters a divisor without rest.

Comment: Shouldn't the outer loop start with 2, number+1 than with 1 for 1 not being a prime number ?

Comment: The range should be `range(2, int(math.sqrt(num)))`, as there is no point in checking the numbers greater than the square root.

Answer (score 0):

the trouble is in your else: statement which has to run outside of the first loop. I recommend the following:

```
def isprime(num):
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            return False
    return True


for num in range(1, number + 1) :
    if isprime(num):
        print num
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your problem

The else statement that you put inside the for loop means that if that number(num) is divisible by this current no represented by i, return true considering it as a prime which IS NOT CORRECT.

> Suggestion

*Your outer loop starts with 1 which should change to 2, as 1 is not a prime number*

> Solution

```
def fun(number):
 #Not counting 1 in the sequence as its not prime
 for num in range(2, number + 1) :
    isPrime = True
    for i in range(2, num) :
         if (num % i) == 0 :
        isPrime = False  
            break
    if isPrime:
        print num
fun(10)
```

**Output**

1

2

3

5

7

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the random number is the range you want the numbers to be within.

I found that the variable i is always equal to 2 in your code.This destroys the purpose of having a second for loop

Prime numbers are numbers that cannot be divisible by 2, 3 or 7, excluding 2, 3 or 7!

With this knowledge I adapted your code to show the true prime numbers.

> solution

```
number = int(input("Enter a random number: "))

for num in range(2,number +1) :
    printnum = True
    if num == 2:
        printnum = True
    elif num == 3:
        printnum = True
    elif num == 7:
        printnum = True
    elif num % 2 == 0:
        printnum = False
    elif num % 3 == 0:
        printnum = False
    elif num % 7 == 0:
        printnum = False

    if printnum == True:
        print(num)
```

Comment: What about 25 then (not a prime: 25 = 5x5)?

Answer (score 0):

This is my method to generate first ten prime numbers with no imports, just simple code with components we are learning on college. I save those numbers into list.

```
def main():
    listaPrim = []
    broj = 0
    while len(listaPrim) != 10:
         broj+= 1
         brojac = 0
         for i in range(1,100):
             if broj % i == 0:
                 brojac += 1
         if brojac == 2:
             listaPrim.append(broj)

    print(listaPrim)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```