# Prime Numbers - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie in `Python` programming and I need a feedback. I wrote a program that prints prime numbers up to the given integer. But the output is different than expected. Could you please give me a feedback about this code. What am I doing wrong and why?

**Thank you so much.**

```
user_integer = int(input("Please enter an integer : "))
for num in range(0, user_integer + 1):
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            break
        else:
            print(num)
```

Comment: Welcome :) It's good practice to say what the output was and what you were expecting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prime Numbers python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391063/prime-numbers-python)

Comment: You should also look at better algorithms, such as [Sieve of Eratosthenes - Finding Primes Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939660/sieve-of-eratosthenes-finding-primes-python)

Comment: There is an example code of finding prime numbers in [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
user_integer = int(input("Please enter an integer : "))
for num in range(0, user_integer + 1):
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            break
        else:
            print(num)
```

will print every odd number, including non-primes. Let num be equal 9 then 9%2==0 is False and else body is executed. You should firstly check *all* potential divisors and then `print` if appriopate that is:

```
user_integer = int(input("Please enter an integer : "))
for num in range(2, user_integer + 1):
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(num)
```

Output (for input `25`):

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
```

Note identation of `else` - here it is part of for-else not if-else, so `print` is done if and only if there was not `break` issued.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is caused by the placement of your else statement.

Essentially, the else statement executes every time the number cannot be divided. So for instance with the number nine:

9 % 2 isn't equal to 0, so it will print 9, even though nine isn't prime.

You could do something like this.

```
user_integer = int(input("Please enter an integer : "))

for num in range(0, user_integer + 1):
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            break
        
    else:
        print(num)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are new at python, better start looking at writing optimized codes. you can use list comprehension to achieve like `[i for i in range(0,user,integer)]`